# Не получается загрузить таблицу из базы данных в DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

подскажите, пожалуйста, почему отображается эта ошибка, при попытке отобразить таблицу `DataFrame` в `colaboratory`?

```
ObjectNotExecutableError: Not an executable object: 'select * from ratings'
```

Хотя в `jupyter` код запускается. Заранее спасибо!

```py
import sqlalchemy 
import psycopg2 
import pandas as pd 
connection = '***' 
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connection) 
connect = engine.connect() 
inspector = sqlalchemy.inspect(engine) 
df = pd.read_sql('select * from ratings', connect) 
df.head()
```

Comment: А где ваш код на питоне, по крайней мере тот кусок, который относится к ошибке? Он должен быть в вопросе. По сути колаб - тот же юпитер, только там версии и питона и библиотек могут быть другие, чем у вас локально.

Comment: Логины-пароли из коннекшена уберите. Вернее, просто удалите свой комментарий. Код я перенёс в вопрос.

Comment: Пока нашёл только такое, но как это с Pandas увязать не пойму: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69490450/objectnotexecutableerror-when-executing-any-sql-query-using-asyncengine